# Save HTML <select> element into variable without creating an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, the javascript kinda looks like this:

```js
var test = $('#selectelement')
console.log(test)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now, when running this code, test becomes an array containing the respective element. So if I want to call this select element from the array, I'd have to code

```
test[0]
```

Now, this is not much of an issue of course, but I'd like to avoid it since an array is NOT what I need here because only one single  element is saved to this variable.

So is there any way to avoid this behavior and instead just have a "normal" variable created (I know JS only knows objects, but at least syntaxwise it should behave like a "normal" variable/primitive value :D)?

Comment: as per your error it seems like you are not including JQuery so please make sure to include it other wise error has occurred like $ is not defined.

Comment: Do you want to hold it as pure html text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's an array because you return a jquery object :

```
 document.getElementById('contents'); //returns a HTML DOM Object
 var contents = $('#contents')//array
```

you can store it in one line

```
 var contents = $('#contents')[0];  //returns a jQuery Object
```

JavaScript objects act similar to associative arrays

Comment: woah, thanks, nice to know this ;) Just learned a bit more about the inner workings of native JS and Jquery commands! :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you had returns the jquery object - what you could do is to get the value of the selected element and use that for the variable. The following code simply updates a variable and consoles it when you change the selected option of the select list.

```js
$('#selectelement').on('change',function(){
  var test = $(this).val();
  console.log(test)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="selectelement">Change me </label>
<select id="selectelement">
  <option selected disabled></option>
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option>option 3</option>
  <option>option 4</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use

```
var test = ('#selectelement')[0];
```

or a more JQuery way,

```
var test = ('#selectelement').get(0);
```

to get the first element into the variable directly.
You can of course also use native functions like this:

```
var test = document.querySelector("#selectelement");
```

which will still give you the only element.